# Python plot not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, osx-elcapitan

The python plot command `show()` is not working inside a subdirectory. However, it is working in the `$HOME` and up to four consecutive subdirectories, e.g. `/home/username/Documents/A/B`. Why is it not working inside `/home/username/Documents/A/B/C` ? Any explanation or remedy?

I have not set any `PYTHONPATH` and working in OS X (El Capitan).

A sample plotting program is given below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.title('f(x)=x^2')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("parabola.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the error given, or the missing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not have permission to write to `/home/username/Documents/A/B/C` directory. In this case I suppose

```
plt.savefig("parabola.png")
```

will throw an exeption preventing

```
plt.show()
```

from execution.
Just one of the things to check.

Comment: No, that's not the case. I have checked by commenting as well. I guess, the problem is not very common or maybe not python-related, rather OS-related (such thing didn't happen in Ubuntu). Hope someone shows up with similar experience.